# About Additions On <div class="container-fluid>

Tags: bootstrap-4

I just learned about Bootstrap 4, and already understand `container-fluid`, but in the free template [24 news](https://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page250/24-news), I found something extra `<.... fh5co_header_bg>` complete like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid fh5co_header_bg">
```

I don't understand that at all. enlightenment please what does that mean?

Comment: If you want to attract users to your question, I'd suggest to improve your styling and to format your code. You could also add the link using a link element. You can have some guidelines [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) about code formatting

Comment: Hey Fahrizal, welcome to StackOverflow! Like @GYBE said, it helps to have better formatted code so your question is more readable. I have formatted yours for you this time around - if you paste HTML elements in your question, they won't render unless you wrap them in backticks to make them code blocks. Take a look at the guidelines GYBE has linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is a open source framework based on html css , sass and jquery

You can also customize ready-made classes on Bootstrap

for example you can custom `.container-fluid`

```
.container-fluid {

     background-color:red;

}
```

or

You can add any class you want

for example :

**html :**

```
<div class="container-fluid custom_class"></div>
```

**css :**

```
.custom_class{

      background-color:red;

}
```

Finally both codes have one output

> If you want to change the bootstrap classes , It is better to add a new class to it like the example above

Answer (score 0):

`fh5co_header_bg` is just a custom CSS class that the template is adding to that `container-fluid` `div` element.

If you look at line 41 of the `sass/style_1.scss` file - you can find its definition:

```
.fh5co_header_bg {
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Which is just setting a background color and a font color for that `div`.

Comment: thank you for the answer, so i understand the ignorance so far